# How to change an object that was mocked?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, moq

In my Unit Test I need to change the value of the object that was mocked before. For example:

```
public class Cell
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    private Cell[,] Cells { get; }

    public Table(Cell[,] cells)
    {
        Cells = cells;
    }

    public void SetCell(int x, int y, string value)
    {
        Cells[x, y].Value = value;
    }
}
```

I want to test `SetCell` method in `Table`.

So, first I mock `Cell`, then I create a `Cell[,]` array of cells, create a `Table` passing array of cells as a parameter.

`SetCell` doesn't work, because (I think) I can't change the object that was mocked before. How can I change it?

Here's my test:

```
ICell[,] cells = new ICell[3, 4];
for (int i = 0; i < cells.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cells.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ICell>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.X).Returns(i);
        mock.Setup(m => m.Y).Returns(j);
        mock.Setup(m => m.Value).Returns("");

        cells[i, j] = mock.Object;
    }
}            


ITable table = new Table(cells);
table.SetCell(0, 0, "TEST"); // Cannot change it here :/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Setup all the properties](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties) so that they can be updated

```
ICell[,] cells = new ICell[3, 4];
for (int i = 0; i < cells.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cells.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ICell>();
        mock.SetupAllProperties();
        mock.Object.X = i;
        mock.Object.Y = j;
        mock.Object.Value = "";

        cells[i, j] = mock.Object;
    }
}

//...other code removed for brevity
```